# Three.js requestAnimationFrame OR TweenMax tick handler

Tags: three.js, gsap

I have been experimenting with [Greensock's TweenMax JS](http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/) and [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/). As both libraries use requestAnimationFrame (rAF), I needed to decide which library should handle this.

If I use rAF built into `Three.js`, it runs around 30fps and is pretty smooth.

If I use `TweenMax` eg: `TweenMax.ticker.addEventListener('tick', animate);` it runs about 55-60fps but is a little choppy.

I can change the fps in `TweenMax` with `TweenMax.ticker.fps(30);` which as expected runs similar to the Three.js rAF version.

My question is which method is preferred and is one considered best practice over the other? Also if I choose Three.js am I able to change the fps in its rAF implementation?

Finally, how would you decide on the fps to suit a wider audience? Limiting to 30fps seems ok but is a bit arbitrary, some users may be capable of much higher rates than I am allowing.

**UPDATE :**

From the feedback from mrdoob and jack, I have tried both rAF in three.js and rAF using TweenMax, with antialias on and off.

antialias on:

```
Three.js rAF (default) - 30fps smooth.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cR7Lx/21/

```
TweenMax rAF (default) - 55-60fps slightly choppy.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cR7Lx/23/

```
TweenMax rAF (fps(30)) - 30fps smooth.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cR7Lx/24/

antialias off:

```
Three.js rAF (default) - 30 - 60fps slightly choppy.
TweenMax rAF (default) - 92-120fps slightly choppy.
TweenMax rAF (fps(30)) - 30fps smooth.
```

Could do with someone who knows how requestAnimationFrame works under the hood to help explain the differences, for now I will use either TweenMax 30fps or Three.js both with antialias on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify, the default TweenMax RAF behavior doesn't put a cap on the fps because...well...that's the point of requestAnimationFrame in the first place - it is intended to be something that the **browser** dictates (and it's typically around 60fps). Setting a specific fps with *TweenMax.ticker.fps()* simply puts a cap on it (unless you set *TweenMax.ticker.useRAF(false)* in which case it will use a *setTimout()* to get as close as possible to the fps you set).

I noticed someone said that you must set an fps in TweenMax in order to make it smooth and I just wanted to clarify that it isn't true - doing so just skips RAF updates if/when they occur too quickly - I can't imagine how that'd make anything smoother. It would likely do the opposite.

Only use *TweenMax.ticker.fps()* if you want to **LOWER** the frame rate below the normal browser refresh rate which, again, is typically around 60fps. If you're looking for the smoothest results, I'd probably stick with the default configuration of TweenMax. You could try turning off requestAnimationFrame and using a very high fps (*TweenMax.ticker.useRAF(false); TweenMax.ticker.fps(100)*), but the down side there is that you lose all the benefits of RAF, like improved battery life on mobile devices when the tab is inactive, synchronized updates with the native browser refreshes, etc.

The biggest cause of jerky behavior is graphics rendering in the browser which is unrelated to the JavaScript animation engine.

I'm not familiar with Three.js, so I can't speak to its capabilities or which option would be better to use to drive your other stuff (sorry). All I can say is I'm a big GreenSock fan (ha ha)

Comment: Jack, I'm also a BIG fan of your libraries. What I have experienced is that leaving rAF as default in Three.js runs smooth but around 30fps, leaving rAF as default in TweenMax runs higher framerate but jerks more because it goes between 55 - 60fps. I can make it smoother if I limit the fps using TweenMax.ticker.fps(30);

Comment: As an aside, there was no wiki entry for tweenmax and tweenlite tags in Stackoverflow, I added some text from your site, as its your library you might want to update the tags!!

Answer (score 0):

When i inspected both implemantation in fact they are actually quite similar. They both use [this](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) implemantation with a small difference.

Three.js implemantation calculate your last call and delay the next call for (16 ms - lastCall) to fixed your fps 60. If it cant make it in 16 ms it 'll naturally wait as long as it takes.

TweenMax implemantation does not fixed your fps initally. Instead you have to call fps manually. Which makes that choppy situation. Because you have to give always right fps value ( not much - not less ) to adjust the delay time.

EDIT :

I have to edit TweenMax behaviour cause i missed the constructor call this.fps(fps) at the end of the ticker class which set default fps to 60 when fps is undefined.

Comment: If Three.js can't make 16ms and waits as long as it takes, how does it remain on 30fps and not jump up to say 55fps? I know the animation is capable of 55fps as I see this using TweenMax implementation.

Comment: How is your order inside the animate function ? You have to call render function always right after the reqestAnimateFrame. If you break that order you can wait more than 16ms which can fix your fps 2 x 16 ms ( 30 fps). And how did you calculate fps value ? Did you use any third party libray like stats.js?

Comment: In three.js I was using requestAnimationFrame(animate); in the animate function, goes like rAF(animate); render(); stats.update(); and yes I am using Stats.js. I don't calculate the fps at all, I left it to both implementations to do it themselves, apart from changing the fps to 30 in TweenMax to see if it was smoother.

Comment: function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();
    stats.update();

 }

Comment: Here's a wild guess. Have you tried setting antialias to false? I noticed Chrome capping the fps to 30 when antialias was set to true.

Comment: @mrdoob I have updated my question, I'm now more confused. Even if Chrome did cap the fps with antialias on, why does it not do that for TweenMax ticker if that also uses rAF?

Comment: Why the capping is happening... I don't know yet. Something in Chrome I think. I don't have a Firefox in hand. Does it happen there too? As per the overall question, if can create a jsfiddle for each cases in your list that would be really really helpful.

Comment: @mrdoob - what are the paths to three.js and rAF now? They are not working for me in my old fiddles...

Comment: jsfiddle needs to update their includes. They are trying to include http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/js/RequestAnimationFrame.js and https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/Three.js. Instead they should be including only https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js

Comment: @Neil did you ever find a solution, or explained answer, to this? The accepted answer doesn't seem to explain it fully.